# Oracle Stored Procedure performance

Tags: oracle11g

I am facing a performance issue in one of my stored procedures.
Following is the pseudo-code:

```
PROCEDURE SP_GET_EMPLOYEEDETAILS(P_EMP_ID IN NUMBER, CUR_OUT OUT REF CURSOR)
IS
BEGIN
  OPEN CUR_OUT FOR
    SELECT EMP_NAME, EMAIL, DOB FROM T_EMPLOYEES WHERE EMP_ID=P_EMP_ID;
END;
```

The above stored procedure takes around 20 seconds to return the result set with let's say P_EMP_ID = 100.

However, if I hard-code employee ID as 100 in the stored procedure, the stored procedure returns the result set in 40 milliseconds.

So, the same stored procedure behaves differently for the same parameter value when the value is hard-coded instead of reading the parameter value.

The table T_EMPLOYEES has around 1 million records and there is an index on the EMP_ID column.

Would appreciate any help regarding this as to how I can improve the performance of this stored procedure or what could be the problem here.

Comment: My first guess would be a missmatch between the type of the parameter (NUMBER in this example) and the type of the database column, but since your code is only pseudo-code, it's hard to tell wether or not this could be the case...

Comment: I have verified the datatype for the column. It is NUMBER.

Answer (score 3):

This may be an issue with skewed data distribution and/or incomplete histograms and/or bad system tuning.

The fast version of the query is probably using an index. The slow version is probably doing a full-table-scan.

In order to know which to do, Oracle has to have an idea of the cardinality of the data (in your case, how many results will be returned). If it thinks a lot of results will be returned, it will go straight ahead and do a full-table-scan as it is not worth the overhead of using an index. If it thinks few results will be returned it will use an index to avoid scanning the whole table.

The issues are:

1. If using a literal value, Oracle knows exactly where to look in the histogram to see how many results would be returned. If using a bind variable, it is more complicated. Certainly, on Oracle 10 it didn't handle this well and just took a guess at the cardinality. On Oracle 11, I am not sure as it can do something called "bind variable peeking" - see [SQL Plan Management](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/articles/sql/11g-sqlplanmanagement-101938.html).
2. Even if it does know the actual value, if your histogram is not up-to-date, it will get the wrong values.
3. Even if it works out an accurate guess as to how many results will be returned, you are still dependent on the Oracle system parameters being correct.

For this last point ... basically, Oracle has some parameters that tell it how fast it thinks a FTS is vs how fast an index look-up is. If these are not correct, it will may do an FTS even if it is a lot slower. See [Burleson](http://www.dba-oracle.com/oracle_tips_cost_adj.htm)

My experience is that Oracle tends to flip to doing FTS way too early. Ideally, as the result set grows in size there should be a smooth transition in performance at the point where it goes from using an index to using an FTS, but in practice the systems seem to be set up to favour bulk work.

Comment: No problem. I have been there with that problem. Don't forget to up-vote if you found the answer useful.